# Determine a basis of $Z(\mathbb{C}S_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, representation-theory

Determine a basis of $Z(\mathbb{C}S_3)$ **explicitly as matrices in the group algebra when the group algebra is written as a direct sum of matrixalgebras.**

---

I know that the dimension of $Z(\mathbb{C}S_3)$ is $3$ the number of conjugacy classes.

And I also know a Basis is $B=\left(\sum_{g \in C_1}g,\sum_{g \in C_2}g,\sum_{g \in C_3}g\right)$ with $C_i$ the conjugacy classes.

But how is it written in terms of Matrices? I especially dont get the **fat** part of the task.

Comment: I think your notation for elements in the direct product of matrix algebras is a bit off. An element of $\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{2\times2}$ is of the form $(a,b,c)$ where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and $c$ is a $2 \times 2$-matrix. The expression $\text{diag}(\lambda,\delta,\mu,\mu)$ does not really make sense as an element of this algebra, but $(\lambda,\delta,\text{diag}(\mu,\mu))$ does.

Comment: but we should be able to bundle the informations in a $4\times 4$ matrix, shouldnt we?

Comment: Of course, you can embed $\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{2\times2}$ into $\mathbb{C}_{4\times4}$, but I do not see any reason to do so. I guess, there is no harm to it, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My solution:*

After thinking about it more and more I came to the conclusion that a solution might look like:

$\mathbb{C}S_3=\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}\times\mathbb{C}_{2\times2}$, so matrices might look like $4\times 4$ Matrices with the center of the $\mathbb{C}_{1\times1}$ part being simply $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and the elements in the center of $\mathbb{C}_{2\times2}$ being $\text{diag}(\mu,\mu)$. So we get the elements in the center of $\mathbb{C}S_3$ as $\text{diag}(\lambda,\delta,\mu,\mu)$ and a basis as:

$$\mathcal{B}=(\text{diag}(1,0,0,0),\,\text{diag}(0,1,0,0),\,\text{diag}(0,0,1,1))$$

feel free to give comments about my attempt for a solution..